# Literature Request Undergraduate, Iterative Methods for System of Nonlinear Equations

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, nonlinear-system

I am looking for literature for bachelor thesis on the topic of:
iterative solution procedure for nonlinear equations and system of nonlinear equations.

It could be in English or German.

Before writing this I searched existing question with relevant tags. I collected interesting references to books below. I would like to know were to start with and where to go into deeps. Have I missed any important author or textbook?

### English

Allen, M. B., & Isaacson, E. L. (2019). Iterative Methods for Linear Systems
Axelsson, O. (1994). Iterative solution methods. Cambridge University Press,.
Demmel, J. W. (1990). Matrix Computations. SIAM Review, 32, 691. https://doi.org/10.1137/1032141
Guckenheimer, J., & Holmes, P. (1986). Nonlinear oscillations, dynamical systems, and bifurcations of vector fields (2. print., rev.corr..). Springer. https://ubdata.univie.ac.at/AC00194373
Guckenheimer, J., & Homes, P. (1983). Nonlinear oscillations, dynamical systems, and bifurcations of vector fields. Springer.
Hermann, M. (2006). Numerische Mathematik. https://doi.org/10.1524/9783486595055
Isaacson, E., & Keller, H. B. (1966). Analysis of numerical methods. Wiley. https://ubdata.univie.ac.at/AC00020487
Trefethen, L. N., & Bau, D. (1997). Numerical linear algebra. SIAM.
Tribbey, W. (2010). Numerical Recipes: The Art of Scientific Computing (3rd Edition) is written by William H. Press, Saul A. Teukolsky, William T. Vetterling, and Brian P. Flannery, and published by Cambridge University Press, © 2007, hardback, ISBN 978-0-521-88068-8, 1235 pp. ACM SIGSOFT Software Engineering Notes, 35, 31. https://doi.org/10.1145/1874391.187410
Wiggins, S. (2003). Introduction to applied nonlinear dynamical systems and chaos (2. ed..). Springer.
L. Ridgway Scot numerical analysis

### German

Saad, Y. (2003). Iterative methods for sparse linear systems (2. ed..). Siam. 
Schneider, M. (1991). Numerische Mathematik.
Schwarz, H. R., & Köckler, N. (2009). Numerische Mathematik (7., überarbeitete Auflage). 
Werner, J. (1992). Numerische Mathematik: 1: Lineare und nichtlineare Gleichungssysteme, Interpolation, numerische Integration: Mit 137 Aufgaben. Vieweg.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried it. Would prefer to look at bibliography of recent book to cover recent literature.