# Approximating the solution to a system of 3 oscillatory ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**ODE System**

I have the following system of ODEs:

$x'(t)=x(t)\frac{z(t)}{Z}-x(t)\frac{x(t)+y(t)}{J}$

$y'(t)=y(t)\left(1-\frac{z(t)}{Z}\right)(1-q)-y(t)\frac{x(t)+y(t)}{J}$

$z'(t)=y(t)\left(1-\frac{z(t)}{Z}\right)(1-q)-mz(t)$,

where all variables and parameters are positive and $0<q<1$.

**Background**

The system exhibits an equilibrium, $\left(\overline{x},\overline{y},\overline{z}\right)$, where $\overline{x}$, $\overline{y}$, and $\overline{z}$ are positive when $J$ is greater than a critical value $J_{Crit}$.

The real parts of the eigenvalues $\left(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3\right)$ corresponding to $\left(\overline{x},\overline{y},\overline{z}\right)$ are all negative when $J>J_{Crit}$.

Upon further analysis of the eigenvalues, one finds that $\left(\overline{x},\overline{y},\overline{z}\right)$ always exhibits oscillations (i.e., two of the eigenvalues are complex).

The answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4607481/determining-an-ode-systems-amplitude-of-oscillation-using-eigenvalues/4607931?noredirect=1#comment9711846_4607931) post showed that the solution to such a 3-dimensional system is well-approximated by

$\overline{V} + Ae^{\sigma t}\cos{\left(\omega t+ \phi\right)} + be^{\lambda_3t} \ \forall \ \overline{V} \in \left(\overline{x},\overline{y},\overline{z}\right)$,

where $A$, $\sigma$, $\omega$, and $\phi$ give the oscillations' amplitude, decay rate, frequency, and initial phase, respectively.

Both $A$ and $b$ are functions of initial conditions, which are $x(0)$, $y(0)$, $z(0)$.

**Question**

In general, how does one calculate $b$ for a 3-dimensional ODE system like the one presented here?

Comment: Just to make sure, is $d$ a parameter? I recommend to rename it to avoid confusion with the difference operator.

Comment: I think that the approximation of the solution has to contain $b e^{\lambda_3 t}$ instead of $b e^{\lambda_3}$.

Comment: @PavelKocourek Updated; thank you for pointing these typos out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the solution
$$
\overline{V} + Ae^{\sigma t}\cos{\left(\omega t+ \phi\right)} + be^{\lambda_3t} 
$$
to be equal to $V_0=(x(0),y(0),z(0))$ at $t=0$. So
$$
\overline{V} + A\cos{\left(\phi\right)} + b = V_0.
$$
Next it needs to be taken into account that $b$ is a multiple of the eigenvector associated with $\lambda_3$ and $A$ is a linear combination of the eigenvectors associated with $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

Comment: Is there a book one can read to learn more about this approximation?

Comment: @MathIsHard A theorem that clarifies under what conditions nonlinear system can be "locally approximated" by its linearisation is the Hartman-Grobman Theorem. You can find useful resource by searching the theorem. One of the classic books on ODEs (that covers this topic) is Nonlinear Oscillations, Dynamical Systems, and Bifurcations of Vector Field by (Applied Mathematical Sciences 42) by Guckenheimer and Holmes. You can find it for example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673057/literature-request-undergraduate-iterative-methods-for-system-of-nonlinear-equa